# Incorrect Syntax When Trying to PIVOT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

Currently I'm getting an incorrect syntax centering around 50mg when trying to PIVOT

```
SELECT 
    50mg, Tab, weight, NR 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT CT, CT_VER 
     FROM PCTXX
     WHERE STRING_4 = '123456') CT1
PIVOT
    (MAX(CT_VER) FOR CT IN ([50mg], [Tab], [weight], [NR])) CT2
```

Comment: which rdbms it is ?

Comment: The rdbms is 2016 sql

Answer (score 1):

Identifiers should start with alphabets. [Rules for identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The first character must be one of the following:
>
> - A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from
>   A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.
> - The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#)

Your 50mg should be put as `[50mg]` as given below.

```sql
SELECT [50mg], Tab, weight, NR From (
SELECT DISTINCT CT, CT_VER FROM PCTXX
Where STRING_4 = '123456') CT1
PIVOT
(MAX(CT_VER) FOR CT IN ([50mg],[Tab],[weight],[NR])) CT
```